# Build an Account Geolocation App Zoom

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, map

I'm trying to get zoom to work with the code from the [Build an Account Geolocation App trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/project/account-geolocation-app). I've passed and got my badge but I'm struggling to figure out how to handle zoom. I did wonder if it might be down to the Esri maps but after changing it to MapBox I had the same issue. What I want to do is make sure the markers remain in the correct place after zooming in or out of the map. They remain in the correct place when panning but stop in the exact same place in the UI when zooming.

This is the default map:

[image]

And after zooming out the Hyatt ends up in the drink:

[image]

For completeness sake, this is the code I tried with MapBox:

```
var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false}).setView([37.784173, -122.401557], 14);
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 20,
    id: '<ID>',
    accessToken: '<TOKEN>'
}).addTo(map);
component.set("v.map", map);
```

Comment: Hi, are you still having the issue? How are you adding the markers to the map in the code?

Comment: HI @Wookie88, I sort of gave it up  - I used the code linked and got nowhere, maybe they've fixed it since then...? If you want to take a crack then grand :-)

Comment: It seems like some mistake in adding markers or with CSS of the map. I have recently been working on map in Lightning and Leaflet and everything was fine. Maybe they patched this. It will be hard to guess what could be wrong without details of your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for looking @Wookie88, I'll take another look myself this afternoon.